# Render backbone template when myModel.fetch() is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

Using [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) I'm trying to fetch a model from my server and based on that, render an underscore template. I first tried it without using the result of the api call using the following render function:

```
render: function(options) {
    this.ticketId = options.ticketId;
    var that = this;
    var ticketModel = new TicketModel({'id': that.ticketId});
    $.when(ticketModel.fetch()).done(function(){
        console.log(ticketModel); // this outputs the correct model
    });
    var template = _.template($('#tab-content-template').html(), {ticketId: that.ticketId});
    this.$el.html(template);
},
```

This works perfectly well. So I tried using the result of the api call to render the template:

```
render: function(options) {
    this.ticketId = options.ticketId;
    var that = this;
    var ticketModel = new TicketModel({'id': this.ticketId});
    $.when(ticketModel.fetch()).done(function(){
        console.log(ticketModel);
        console.log($('#tab-content-template').html());
        var template = _.template($('#tab-content-template').html(), {ticketId: that.ticketId});
        this.$el.html(template);
    });
},
```

but unfortunately, this results in an error saying

> Uncaugt TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined.

The weird thing is that it outputs the html in the console correctly resulting from `console.log($('#tab-content-template').html());`. The error I get is on the line which reads `this.$el.html(template);`

How can it be that it first is able to get the html(), and after that it says it can't find the property html? I'm totally stuck here.. :S

All tips are welcome!

Comment: learnt something new from this didn't realise that fetch returned $.deferred object, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this no longer refers to what you think it refers to. in your code you have placed

```
var that = this;
```

this is a common pattern/trick to allow the closure to retain the context of "this" when being executed. Inside your closure "that" would now refer to what you think "this" should refer to.

Try changing "this" to "that"

```
 $.when(ticketModel.fetch()).done(function(){
        console.log(ticketModel);
        console.log($('#tab-content-template').html());
        var template = _.template($('#tab-content-template').html(), {ticketId: that.ticketId});
        that.$el.html(template);
    });
```

I usally make use of jQuery's proxy function that ensures when a function is executed you can be confident of the context in which it is running

```
 $.when(ticketModel.fetch()).done($.proxy(function(){
        console.log(ticketModel);
        console.log($('#tab-content-template').html());
        var template = _.template($('#tab-content-template').html(), {ticketId: that.ticketId});
        this.$el.html(template);
    },this));
```

oh your other question about why is $('#tab-content-template').html() working, this is because you are using JQuery directly which is in the global namespace so there for accessible where as $el is a property of your view so if you can't access your view you can't access the property.

Answer (score 0):

See http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch - in `options` argument it accepts `success` and `error` callbacks:

```
ticketModel.fetch({
    success: function(model, response, options) {
        // render the template
    }
});
```

Also if you need to use a context of current view object in this callback you can use Underscore/Lo-Dash `_.bind()` function to pass the context:

```
ticketModel.fetch({
    success: _.bind(function(model, response, options) {
        // Render the template using some method of the view:
        this.renderMyTemplate(model);
    }, this)
});
```

or just pass the method itself:

```
ticketModel.fetch({
    success: this.renderMyTemplate,
    error: this.handleFetchError
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a $.when here, backbone now returns a promise for fetch call. Below code should work for you. Also consider compiling template outside render function. Compiling template is bit heavy task, should be cached once done.

```
var _this = this;
ticketModel.fetch().done(function () {
    var template = _.template($('#tab-content-template').html(), {ticketId: that.ticketId});
    _this.$el.html(template);
});
```